# C# and XPath - how to query

Tags: c#, xpath

I have an XML-File, which has the following structure:

```
<mediawiki ...>
  <siteinfo>...</siteinfo>
  <page>
    <title>The Title</title>
    <id>42</id>
    ...
  </page>
  ... more page items ...
</mediawiki>
```

I red a bit about XPath-Query and wrote the following code:

```
_xmlArticlesDocument = new XmlDocument();
_xmlArticlesDocument.Load(xmlArticlesFileName);
```

Now I want to get a grip on a page Element with a given id-Subelement. So I wrote:

```
XmlNode node = _xmlArticlesDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode
               ("//mediawiki/page[id=" + id.ToString() + "]");
```

but node is always null. I have tried several querys, including "page/id", "page", "/page", "//page" to get *anything*, but node is always null. I have checked via quick inspection the _xmlArticlesDocument variable and it contains the correct XML-file with the expected structure.

It seems to me, that I have missed something very basic, but have no idea what. Maybe someone here has an idea?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query looks right on the basis of what you shown us so far.  However I suspect behin the "..." on the mediawiki element there is a xmlns="...." attribute right?

That'll be what is tripping you up I suspect.  You will need code like this:-

```
 XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(_xmlArticlesDocument.NameTable);
 nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "the-namespace-in-them-xmlns-attribute");
 XmlNode page = _xmlArticlesDocument.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//a:page[id={0}]", id), nsmgr);
```

Comment: This is the way forward, I had loads of trouble with it but once you get to grips with this, it is easy. :)

Comment: Hit the nail on the head! Problem was the missing namespacemanager, that wasn't mentioned in the tutorial I red. A little change in the query is needed though, 'cause the id-Element is in the namespace too: "a:page[a:id=" + id.toString() + "]" does the job right. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
_xmlArticlesDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode
               ("page[id='" + id.ToString() + "']"); // Note the single quotes
```

Also, if any of the XML nodes are in a namespace that is not the default one (i.e. `<mediawiki xmlns="whatever">`) then you are also going to need an [`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx).

Comment: The // should move the query to the start of the document.

Comment: I didn't suggest using the //... or am I not understanding your point?

Comment: Don't forget to make sure/check that `id` does not contain single quotes, or `SelectSingleNode()` will fail because of invalid XPath.

Comment: @Sean:  Sorry it was an extremely boiled down comment that the original query should work anyway (I was assuming you had missed the // in the question).

Comment: the single quotes can be ommited, as I tested right now. Problem was, as you mentioned, the missing namespace thing.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Linq to XML. I am a XML noob too, and I am finding it to be easier, the XMLDocument.

Comment: I was just going to suggest that as well.  If you don't already know XPath and only need it to parse through XML in C#.Net, then Linq to XML is the way to go.

Comment: I would agree that if you don't already have XPath under your belt you might find the LINQ approach better since the skills are more transferable.

Comment: Ah, I think these are starting up problems. After getting the bits together, it looks very intuitive to me. And with this awesome community here at StackOverflow, those starting up problems won't be unresolved for long ;)