# SelectSingleNode returns null when tag contains xmlNamespace

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, selectsinglenode, selectnodes

I'm loading a string into an XML document that contains the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">                  
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="clsWorker.cs" />        
  </ItemGroup>      
</Project>
```

Then I'm loading all into an `XmlDocument`:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(Xml);
```

Then the following problem occurs:

```
XmlNode Node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//Compile"); // returns null
```

When I remove the `xmlns` attribute from the root element (`Project`), it works fine.

How do I get `SelectSingleNode` to return the relevant element?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You should use an [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) in your call to [SelectSingleNode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx):

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("msbld", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//msbld:Compile", ns);
```

Comment: Is this applied to `SelectNodes`?

Comment: @T.S., yes. `SelectSingleNode("xpath")` is roughly equivalent to `SelectNodes("xpath")[0]`.

Comment: where did `msbld` come from?

Comment: @Alex, that's arbitrary, I could have used anything. The important thing is to use the same name in the call to `AddNamespace()` and in the namespace prefix.

Comment: @Alex Jolig, Assuming your schemas are all specified in the header you can do something like this to dynamically add them all:

    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
    foreach (XmlAttribute curAttribute in xml.DocumentElement.Attributes)
    {
        if (curAttribute.Prefix.Equals("xmlns"))
        {
            ns.AddNamespace(curAttribute.LocalName, curAttribute.Value);
        }
    }

Comment: How to omit all that namespace nonsense, tha complicates the simple,  when we are sure the source xml is consistent and homogeneous?

Answer (score 26):

Taken right from the [documentation of `SelectSingleNode()` on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx):

> **Note**
>   If the XPath expression does not include a prefix, it is assumed that the 
>   namespace URI is the empty namespace. **If your XML includes a default 
>   namespace, you must still add a prefix and namespace URI to the 
>   XmlNamespaceManager; otherwise, you will not get a node selected.** For 
>   more information, see [Select Nodes Using XPath Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx.aspx).

And the immediately following sample code is

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "http://www.lucernepublishing.com");
XmlNode book = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ab:book", nsmgr);
```

[It's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585812/using-xpath-with-default-namespace-in-c) [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345/xpaths-and-default-namespaces) [as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524804/how-do-i-use-xpath-with-a-default-namespace-with-no-prefix) [if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809496/why-is-selectsinglenode-returning-null) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730710/xpath-is-there-a-way-to-set-a-default-namespace-for-queries) [would](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561822/xpath-on-an-xml-document-with-namespace) [be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100156/how-to-select-nodes-with-xpath-in-c) "[hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607543/problems-in-selecting-a-node-in-xml-with-namespace-using-xpath) [knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194675/c-and-xpath-how-to-query)". ;-)

Answer (score 7):

This way you don't need to specify namespace:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml("your xml");
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/*[local-name() = 'Compile']");
XmlNode nodeToImport = xmlDoc2.ImportNode(node, true);
xmlDoc2.AppendChild(nodeToImport);
```

Comment: For me it's necessary to use //*[local-name instead of /*[local-name

Answer (score 4):

Since the 'ItemGroup' may have multiple 'Compile' children, and you specifically want the 'Compile' children of 'Project/ItemGroup', the following will return all of the desired 'Compile' children and no others:

```
XmlDocument projectDoc = new XmlDocument();
projectDoc.Load(projectDocPath);
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(projectDoc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("msbld", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
XmlNodeList xnList = projectDoc.SelectNodes(@"/msbld:Project/msbld:ItemGroup/msbld:Compile", ns);
```

Note that the 'msbld:' namespace specification needs to precede each node level.

Comment: upvoted for the warning about multiple namespace specification.