# Using C# to find nodes within .csproj files

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having trouble trying to select a particular node from a .csproj file I've read in as a XDocument.

```
XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load("The full path of the .csproj file");
```

This loads the .csproj file into a XDocument without issue. I've tried `Descendants`, `Elements`, etc etc to try to get `TheNodeIWant` and its value, but cannot figure out why I keep getting no results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <TheNodeIWant>The String I Want </TheNodeIWant>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <PropertyGroup>
        .......
        </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

How can I select `TheNodeIWant` and retrieve its value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4171468/1301310

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(@"c:\test.txt");

XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("msbld", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//msbld:TheNodeIWant", ns);

if (node != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [MSBuild Project class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.project.aspx) to better use `csproj` from code.

Comment: If only it worked. Has issues finding MSBuildBinPath, thinks it's my current app directory. Useless.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [Xpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9x81sf5a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to navigate inside your csproj file.