# Get XML value from xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a short question, i would like to get the Type Value "someType"
from a XML Structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UniversalInterchange xmlns="http://www.cargowise.com/Schemas/Universal/2011/11" version="1.1">
    <Header>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <UniversalShipment xmlns="http://www.cargowise.com/Schemas/Universal/2011/11" version="1.1">
            <Shipment>
                <DataContext>
                    <DataTargetCollection>
                        <DataTarget>
                            <Type>someType</Type>
                        </DataTarget>
                    </DataTargetCollection>
                </DataContext>
                <FileType>
                  <SecondType>not this type</SecondType>
                </FileType>
      </Shipment>
     </UniversalShipment>
    </Body>
</UniversalInterchange>
```

I have tryed it with more possible solutions but nothing gives me the type

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString); 

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/UniversalInterchange/Body/UniversalShipment/Shipment/DataContext/DataTargetCollection/DataTarget");

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
   string type = xn["Type"].InnerText;
   Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", type);
}
```

Whats wrong ?

Comment: Have you set a break-point on string type = xn["Type"].InnerText; and checked what properties it has?

Comment: yes, it's null but the XPath is right

Comment: No, the XPath isn't right - it isn't using the right namespaces. Personally I'd use LINQ to XML, which makes this trivial, but you can do it with XPath if you really want to...

Comment: To @StuartSmith 's point you're going to need to [use the XmlNameSpaceManger](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4171468/119477)

Comment: I want to solve it with the most current way (LINQ?) but i don't know how i can solve this with LINQ

Comment: Xml is invalid, <Shipment> and <UniversalShipment> tags never end

Comment: XML Sample is updated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested, XDocument is the way to go. There's also a namespace involved, meaning you need to do something like this:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

XNamespace ns = "http://www.cargowise.com/Schemas/Universal/2011/11";

var value = xDoc
    .Element(ns + "UniversalInterchange")
    .Element(ns + "Body")
    .Element(ns + "UniversalShipment")
    .Element(ns + "Shipment")
    .Element(ns + "DataContext")
    .Element(ns + "DataTargetCollection")
    .Element(ns + "DataTarget")
    .Element(ns + "Type")
    .Value;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242175/get-resutls-from-xml-with-more-than-one-line

Could you check this ?