# Get Resutls from XML with more than one line

Tags: c#, xml

I want get Order Lines for each Order and bring them to an EMail Body as Table like

Value 1  | Value 2 | Value 3

12345           ABC           X1_

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><UniversalInterchange xmlns= "http://www.designworker/namespace" version="1.1">
    <Header> </Header>
    <Body>
        <UniversalShipment xmlns="http://www.designworker/namespace" version="1.1">
            <Shipment>
                <DataContext>
                    <DataTargetCollection>
                        <DataTarget>
                            <Type>SMTPTYPE</Type>
                        </DataTarget>
                    </DataTargetCollection>
                </DataContext>
                <Order>
                    <OrderNumber>99348234234</OrderNumber>
                    <OrderLineCollection>
                        <OrderLine>
                            <LineNumber>1</LineNumber> 
                            <OrderedQty>455.000</OrderedQty>
                            <OrderedQtyUnit>
                                <Code>MORE</Code>
                            </OrderedQtyUnit>
                            <Product>
                                <Code>999LAM01</Code> 
                                <Description>New Design Work</Description>
                            </Product>
                            <QuantityMet>1.000</QuantityMet> 
                            <ShortfallQuantity>0</ShortfallQuantity> 
                        </OrderLine>
                        <OrderLine>
                            <LineNumber>2</LineNumber> 
                            <OrderedQty>655.000</OrderedQty>
                            <OrderedQtyUnit>
                                <Code>SOME</Code>
                            </OrderedQtyUnit>
                            <Product>
                                <Code>999LAM02</Code> 
                                <Description>OLD Design Work </Description>
                            </Product>
                            <QuantityMet>3.000</QuantityMet> 
                            <ShortfallQuantity>45</ShortfallQuantity> 
                        </OrderLine>
                    </OrderLineCollection>
                </Order>
            </Shipment>
        </UniversalShipment>
    </Body>
</UniversalInterchange>
```

I have tried to solve this with this code:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlValue);
            XNamespace nsp = ns;
            try
            {
                var value = xDoc
                    .Element(nsp + "UniversalInterchange")
                    .Element(nsp + "Body")
                    .Element(nsp + "UniversalShipment")
                    .Element(nsp + "Order")
                    .Element(nsp + "OrderLine")
                    .Element(nsp + "LineNumber")
                    .Value;
                return value;
```

But when I have more than one Line in the Order it won't work.
How can I solve this on a better way ?

Comment: [Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) vs. [Elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348975.aspx)

Comment: Also Elements. and than I will get all Line from an Order ?

Comment: `var orderLines = [...].Elements(nsp + "OrderLine"); var lineNumbers = orderLines.SelectMany(ol => ol.Element(nsp + "LineNumber")); var lineNumberValues = lineNumbers.SelectMany(ln => ln.Value);`

Comment: that looks good but i need Line Number and Product Code in one line and for the next line number and the next product code a new line

Comment: 1. Create a small class to store the data you need from an order line (line number and product code). 2. Create a `List<ThatClass>`. `foreach(var orderLine in orderLines) { \\ create a new object of ThatClass, fill it with the info of the current orderLine and then add it to the list }`. 3. for each line you want, go through all the items in the list, concatenate the values of the one property you want in that line, finish with a newLine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the navigation path is missing a few .Element()-calls.

```
var orderLines = xDoc
   .Element(nsp + "UniversalInterchange")
   .Element(nsp + "Body")
   .Element(nsp + "UniversalShipment")
   .Element(nsp + "Shipment")
   .Element(nsp + "Order")
   .Element(nsp + "OrderLineCollection")
   .Elements(nsp + "OrderLine");

// 1, 2
var lineNumbers = orderLines.Select(x => x.Element(nsp + "LineNumber").Value);
```

Whenever an element isn't found, null is returned from .Element(). You should also use .Elements() instead of .Element() if you expect multiple entries.

Comment: c# the ':' character hexadecimal value 0x3a cannot be included in a name will come when i do it so