# Null value when trying to retrieve a node from XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-namespaces

I need to read and update the value of CollectionPlan -> CheckpointOptions -> ThreadCheckpoints -> Mode from xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CollectionPlan xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:visualstudio:tracelog">
  <StartupInfo>
    <LogFileName>
    </LogFileName>
    <LogFileDirectory>C:\LogFiles</LogFileDirectory>
    <MaximumLogFileSize>16384</MaximumLogFileSize>
  </StartupInfo>
  <CheckpointOptions>
    <ThreadCheckpoints>
      <Mode>FixedEventRate</Mode>
      <StartRate>30000</StartRate>
    </ThreadCheckpoints>
    <NotifyPointCheckpoints>
      <Mode>FixedEventRate</Mode>
      <StartRate>1000</StartRate>
    </NotifyPointCheckpoints>
  </CheckpointOptions>
  <!-- many other nodes -->
 </CollectionPlan>
```

For this, I have  following code.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("urn:", "schemas-microsoft-com:visualstudio:tracelog");
doc.Load(@"c:\myXml.xml");
var aNodes = doc.SelectSingleNode("CollectionPlan/CheckpointOptions/ThreadCheckpoints/Mode", manager);
```

However aNodes is coming as NULL. What I have incorrect here?

Comment: You need to use the `urn:` prefix for each node in the string passed to `SelectSingleNode`.  See [XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode and xmlNamespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171451/xmldocument-selectsinglenode-and-xmlnamespace-issue).

Comment: Also the namespace is wrong, it should be `"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:visualstudio:tracelog"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. You need use the correct root namespace that appears in the XML.  It is `"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:visualstudio:tracelog"`.
2. In the call to `AddNamespace`, don't use a `:` in the prefix string.  The `:` character is not a part of the namespace prefix, it is used to separate the prefix from the element local name when parsing the query string.
3. In the call to `SelectSingleNode`, you need to prefix your node local names in the query with the namespace prefix `"urn:"` which you defined with your namespace manager, since the XML nodes you are searching for are in the corresponding namespace.

Thus the following should work:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("urn", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:visualstudio:tracelog");
doc.Load(@"c:\myXml.xml")
var aNodes = doc.SelectSingleNode("urn:CollectionPlan/urn:CheckpointOptions/urn:ThreadCheckpoints/urn:Mode", manager);
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HYfycr).

Comment: I would not put "urn" as the prefix.  That is the protocol that is part of the namespace.  The prefix is a string that the NameSpaceManager uses for identifying the namespace.  It is the key into the collection the manager uses to keep track of the namespaces. "Prefix" is kind of a misnomer.  So something like "TraceLog" or "TLog" would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use:

```
manager.AddNamespace("tlog", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:visualstudio:tracelog");
```

urn is the protocol, not the prefix.  It is part of the namespace specification so you need to put it in there.