# How to Parse Nested XML Nodes in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am very new to C#, but it seems as though this should be pretty straight forward. I am trying to parse an XML string returned from a web feed that looks like this:

```
<autnresponse xmlns:autn="http://schemas.autonomy.com/aci/">
  <action>QUERY</action>
  <response>SUCCESS</response>
  <responsedata>
    <autn:numhits>6</autn:numhits>
    <autn:hit>
      <autn:reference>http://something.what.com/index.php?title=DPM</autn:reference>
      <autn:id>548166</autn:id>
      <autn:section>0</autn:section>
      <autn:weight>87.44</autn:weight>
      <autn:links>Castlmania,POUCH</autn:links>
      <autn:database>Postgres</autn:database>
      <autn:title>A Pouch and Mail - Castlmania</autn:title>
      <autn:content>
        <DOCUMENT>
          <DRETITLE>Castlmania Pouch and Mail - Castlmania</DRETITLE>
          <DRECONTENT>A paragraph of sorts that would contain content</DRECONTENT>
        </DOCUMENT>
      </autn:content>
  </autn:hit>
  <autn:hit>...</autn:hit>
  <autn:hit>...</autn:hit>
  <autn:hit>...</autn:hit>
  <autn:hit>...</autn:hit>
</autnresponse>
```

with no luck.
I am using this code to start:

```
XmlDocument xmlString = new XmlDocument();
xmlString.LoadXml(xmlUrl);

XmlElement root = xmlString.DocumentElement;
XmlNode GeneralInformationNode =
root.SelectSingleNode("//autnresponse/responsedata/autn:hit");

foreach (XmlNode node in GeneralInformationNode)
{
  Console.Write("reference: "+node["autn:reference"]+" Title:"+node["DRETITLE"]+"<br />);
}
```

And I would like to print the DRETITLE and autn:reference element of within each of the autn:hit elements. Is that even doable with my approach?

I have tried looking and several example on the good old web like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169598/Parse-XML-Documents-by-XMLDocument-and-XDocument) to no avail.

The error that comes back is:

> System.Xml.XPath.XpathEception {NameSpace Manager or XsltContext
>   needed. ...}

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

In trying to use XmlNamespaceManager, one has to give it a url to the schema definition like so:

```
XmlNamespaceManager namespmng = new XmlNamespaceManager (xmlString.NameTable);
namespmng.AddNamespace("autn","http://someURL.com/XMLschema");
```

The problem seems to be that now the error is gone, but the data is not displaying. I should mention that I am working off of a machine that does not have internet connectivity. The other thing is the schema seems to be unavailable. I am guessing that XmlNamespaceManager would work once able to connect to the internet right?

Comment: Looks like a dup of [XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode and xmlNamespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171451/xmldocument-selectsinglenode-and-xmlnamespace-issue).

Comment: Similar but quite different in the sense that they are trying to improve how they are returning an element. I am trying to return nested elements within a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `System.Xml.Linq` it could be something like this:

```
var doc = XElement.Load(xmlUrl);
var ns = doc.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("autn");

foreach (var hit in doc.Descendants(ns + "hit"))
{
   var reference = hit.Element(ns + "reference").Value;
   var dretitle = hit.Descendants("DRETITLE").Single().Value;
   WriteLine($"ref: {reference} title: {dretitle}");
}
```

Comment: This was the money shot! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the exception you're getting is because you haven't loaded the namespace using the `XmlNamespaceManager` for the xml you're parsing.  Something like this:

```
XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlString.NameTable);
if (root.Attributes["xmlns:autn"] != null)
{
    uri = root.Attributes["xmlns:autn"].Value;
    namespaceManager.AddNamespace("autn", uri);
}
```

Secondly, what you're trying to do is possible.  I'd suggest using `root.SelectNodes(<your xpath here>)` which will return a collection of autn:hit nodes that you can loop through instead of `SelectSingleNode` which will return one node.  Within that you can drill down to the content/DOCUMENT/DRETITLE and pull the text for the DRETITLE node using either `XmlNode.Value` if you select the text specifically or `XmlNode.InnerText` on the DRETITLE node.

Comment: Can you elaborate on root.SelectNodes syntax and how that might look?

Comment: This approach does not seem to work with the URI is not available.

Comment: If you can't reach your namespace you'll have to add the namespace prefix in your xpath queries for each element as they are for the nodes.  `SelectNodes` syntax should be similar to what you did for SelectSingleNode.  It'll return a list of nodes you can loop through using a foreach.  To get the specific value you can select the node (via selectsinglenode using xpath) that contains the value you want.