# XmlNodeList.SelectSingleNode() returning null for different XML formats

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller

I have an XML like:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="name1" value="value1">
     <add name="name2" value="value2">
  </connectionStrings>
<configuration>
```

In this i get

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("connectionStrings");
foreach(XmlNode xn in nodeList)
{
  var anode = xn.SelectSingleNode("add");
}
```

Here "var anode" is returning me right values of "name" attribute.
But when my xml is like:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="name1" value="value1">
     <add name="name2" value="value2">
  </connectionStrings>
<configuration>
```

I get anode as null.

Please help.

Comment: You need to use a namespace in the query.  See [XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode and xmlNamespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171451/xmldocument-selectsinglenode-and-xmlnamespace-issue).  Also, `GetElementsByTagName()` is deprecated.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk(v=vs.110).aspx): *It is recommended that you use the XmlNode.SelectNodes or XmlNode.SelectSingleNode method instead of the GetElementsByTagName method.*

Answer (score -1):

The following code works for me:

```
var xElement = XElement.Load("Sample.xml");

var elements = xElement.Elements().Elements();

            foreach (var element in elements)
            {
                var name = element.Attribute("value").Value;
            }
```

Please try this.

Note: The Sample.xml contains:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="name1" value="value1"/>
     <add name="name2" value="value2"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The xml file which you posted didnot close properly. Above xml is properly formatted.

Comment: May I know why down vote. Just wondering what I am missing. The code works for me.