# how to get specific nodes from XML string in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to get "cust_name" and "code" nodes from a web API XML response below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cust_list xmlns="http://example.com">
    <cust>
        <cust_id>1234</cust_id>
        <cust_name>abcd</cust_name>
        <cust_type>
            <code>2006</code>
        </cust_type>
    </cust>
</cust_list>
```

I'm writing the response as string to XMLDocument and trying to read from it. Below is my code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://serviceURI");
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "Application/XML";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(responseValue);

    string node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/cust_list/cust/cust_name").InnerText;
    string node2 = doc.SelectSingleNode("/cust_list/cust/cust_type/code").InnerText;
}
```

I'm trying to target specific nodes but getting "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: This is almost certainly due to the namespace part. Any reason you don't want to use LINQ to XML, which makes namespace-handling rather simpler?

Comment: Here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4171468/126995

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode and xmlNamespace issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171451/xmldocument-selectsinglenode-and-xmlnamespace-issue)

Comment: @Jon Skeet this is part of a big application and linq was not used anywhere in the application. isn't there anyway i can get the values of specific nodes by Xpath?

Comment: @Soonts will the namespace be same all the time? because the service is not managed by us. we are consuming it from a different resource.

Comment: I think it’s OK. Typically, when people change their XML namespaces, they do it for the reason they have also changed their XML schema. If the developers of the service you’re consuming will do that, you’ll need to fix your client code anyway.

Comment: Also, see the comment by Ravendarksky to the answer I’ve linked above.

Comment: `XmlNamespaceManager` raises an exception when trying to add the reserved namespace `xmlns`.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you *can* do so - but you shouldn't feel afraid to start using LINQ to XML just for one part of the application. Introduce it gradually - it's a *much* nicer XML API. If you never feel you can use any new features because they weren't used in the original code, you'd be stuck without generics, lambda expressions, asynchrony etc...

Comment: @Soonts so, according to Ravendarsky's code will it retrieve the latest namespace whenever it is updated? i dont want my application to break whenever the namespace is updated.

Comment: @jonSkeet Thanks for your advise. i can use LINQ if it allows me to target specific nodes(without using namespace). can you please add an answer on how to do that with LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
XNamespace ns = (string)xml.Attribute("xmlns");
var customers = xml.Elements(ns + "cust")
    .Select(c => new
    {
        name = (string)c.Element(ns + "cust_name"),
        code = (int)c.Element(ns + "cust_type")
            .Element(ns + "code")
    });
```

In this example an `XElement` is parsed from the input string.

A `Namespace` is also created using the attribute `xmlns`. Note how this is used when selecting elements.

All cust elements in the root element are selected and projected into a new anonymous type that currently declares a `string` name and an `int` code (you can extend this as needed).

So for example, to get the name of the first customer you could do the following:

```
string name = customers.First().name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! that worked. but i had to add "First().value" to the end of "string name = customers.First().name.First().Value" for it return actual innerXML value other wise it is returning some object path.