# How to get xml tag which is in DataSet1 tag(C#)?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DataSet1 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd">
  <objectdata>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>CM 08 10 AT</name>
  </objectdata>
</DataSet1>
```

I'm trying to get the values id and name from this xml in C# like that:

```
string folder = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString() + "/ObjectFolder/object.xml";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(folder);
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/DataSet1/objectdata");
```

I've tried also:

```
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/objectdata");
```

But it doesn't work either. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Your root node has a default [XML namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) so see [XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode and xmlNamespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4171451/3744182).

Comment: Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I25p6S) showing how to use the duplicate answer.