# C# Xml SelectSingleNode returns null

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, selectsinglenode

I have this xml and want to extract the first Country out of the xml

```
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
   <NewDataSet>
      <Table>
         <Country>Hong Kong</Country>
         <City>Cheung Chau</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
         <Country>Hong Kong</Country>
         <City>Hong Kong Inter-National Airport</City>
      </Table>
   </NewDataSet>
</string>
```

here's what I did:

```
value = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("string/NewDataSet/Table[1]/Country").InnerText;
```

This always throw an exception not set to an instance of object as the selectsinglenode always retursn null. Strange thing is I have already tested this xpath using [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) and it does return me the node I want.

I have googled to find a solution and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161317/xml-document-selectsinglenode-returns-null) suggesting that I have to add namespace, here's what I did:

```
  var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
  nsmgr.AddNamespace("string", "http://www.webserviceX.NET");
  var node = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("string/NewDataSet/Table[1]/Country", nsmgr);
```

Still I have the same exception. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks :)

Comment: In that answer you missed that the namespace is added to a node by prepending it to the nodename with a colon. As you named you namespace `string` you'll have to prepend all nodenames with `string:` so you'll get `string:string\string:NewDataSet\...` etc.

Comment: Your root node has a [default XML namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) so see [XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode and xmlNamespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4171451/3744182).  Recent related question: [How to get xml tag which is in DataSet1 tag(C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47829282/3744182) with associated fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/I25p6S showing how to do it correctly.

Comment: @rene those should be `/` not \ (backslash) characters I believe.

Comment: @dbc Oh, yeah, you're right, I'm on my first coffee, you can tell. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `XmlNamespaceManager`

```
XmlNamespaceManager namespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
namespaces.AddNamespace("sp", "http://www.webserviceX.NET");
var nodes = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//sp:NewDataSet/sp:Table[1]/sp:Country", namespaces);
```