# SelectSingleNode returns a null value

Tags: powershell

I am trying to select and remove a single node from an XML document. Sample code and XML below:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content MyXml.xml    
$xml.MigrationTable.Mapping[1].SelectSingleNode("DestinationSameAsSource")
```

This currently returns nothing. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171451/xmldocument-selectsinglenode-and-xmlnamespace-issue) shows a C# example for including the namespace when calling the `SelectSingleNode()` method.

How can I include the namespace with `SelectSingleNode()` in PowerShell?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<MigrationTable xmlns="http://microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/GPOOperations/MigrationTable" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Mapping>
<Type>LocalGroup</Type>
<Source>Group1@Contoso.local</Source>
<Destination>Group2@contoso.local</Destination>
</Mapping>
<Mapping>
<Type>Unknown</Type>
<Source>Network Service</Source>
<DestinationSameAsSource/>
</Mapping>
<Mapping>
<Type>Unknown</Type>
<Source>Local Service</Source>
<DestinationSameAsSource/>
</Mapping>
</MigrationTable>
```

Comment: you don't need the xmlnamespace if you use the auto-properties like you already did with the "Mapping" node. you can access the node like this -> $xml.MigrationTable.Mapping[1].DestinationSameAsSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Powershell syntax for NameTable handling is pretty similar to C#. After loading the data, create a NamespaceManager based on the XML document.

To select elements, a [dummy namespace prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4171470/503046) needs to be used, in this sample `x` is added and used in Xpath. Like so,

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content MyXml.xml
$nsmgr = new-object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$nsmgr.AddNameSpace("x", "http://microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/GPOOperations/MigrationTable")
$xml.MigrationTable.Mapping[1].SelectSingleNode("x:DestinationSameAsSource", $nsmgr)
```

Comment: Does it make sense to get the Namespaceuri from the already parsed xml? `$nsmgr.AddNameSpace("x", $xml.MigrationTable.xmlns)`

Comment: @LotPings Propably. I learned the forementioned way from an article [written in 2005](https://writingontablets.com/Using-SelectSingleNode-(or-SelectNodes)-on-XML-where-the-default-namespace-has-been-set) and have been using it ever since.